# Split string with random beginning

Tags: vbscript

I've got a string like this one: `value1-value2-value3-value4-20160928-LastValue`

I have to split this string with VBScript. So it should be easy by using `Split` function.

My problem: the values before the date (20160928) are random.
It means I could have 1 value or 10 values.

Date and LastValue will be always at the same place.

How can I identify the date and the last value in my array (creating with the `Split` function)?

Comment: What's wrong with the split function you mention?  How is it not working for you?  Confused...

Comment: In my exemple date will be SplitList(4) and LastValue will be SplitList(5). if i've got a sentence with only value1-20160928-LastValue, the position ion the array will not be the same. And i have to identify the date and the last value to complete my code.

Comment: So then what's the problem?  Take the second to last value in the array and the last value.

Comment: And how can i do that ?

Comment: With ubound, of course.  I had assumed you knew that or at least knew how to google.

Comment: Now i know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5) the string. The [`UBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t) function gives you the last index in the array. The second-last index is the last index minus 1.

```
s = "value1-value2-value3-value4-20160928-LastValue"
a = Split(s, "-")
WScript.Echo "Last value: " & a(UBound(a))
WScript.Echo "Date:       " & a(UBound(a)-1)
```